# vue2 call a parent function using $emit from component

Tags: methods, vuejs2, emit

i'm trying to call a parent methods from child component, but it seems not working.. here the code:

**index.html**

```
<div class="percorso"v-on:removeall="pathlengthTozero()">
</div>
```

**component**

```
Vue.component('lista-percorso', {
template:`
<div class="col-lg-2 col-xs-2">
    <div class="removeall pull-right" v-on:click="removeall()"></div>
</div>`,

    methods:{
    removeall : function(){
        this.listaSelezionati = [];
        this.$emit('removeall');
    }
}
```

**parent method**

```
    pathlengthTozero : function(){
       il_tuo_percorso = [''];
    }
```

seems that "pathlengthTozero" is not called on emit which is the correct way to use it?

Comment: You can use v-on to listen to DOM events. v-on:removeall doesn't make any sense.

Comment: Where did you use this `lista-percorso` component?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You need to put this `v-on:removeall="pathlengthTozero"` to the component `<lista-percorso>` like below,

```
<lista-percorso v-on:removeall="pathlengthTozero"></lista-percorso>
```

and `this.$emit` will able to fire the parent method.

**Sample Demo:**

```js
Vue.component('lista-percorso', {
template:`
<div class="col-lg-2 col-xs-2">
    <div class="removeall pull-right" v-on:click="removeall()">xxxxxxxxxx</div>
</div>`,

    methods:{
    removeall : function(){
        this.listaSelezionati = [];
        this.$emit('removeall');
    }
  }
})



var App = new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  methods:{
    pathlengthTozero : function(){
      alert('hello'); 
      il_tuo_percorso = [''];
    }
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue"></script>

<div id="app">
  <div class="percorso" ></div>

  <lista-percorso v-on:removeall="pathlengthTozero"></lista-percorso>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

you should put the event listener on the child conponent where it is used

```
<div class="percorso">
    <lista-percorso v-on:removeall="pathlengthTozero"></lista-percorso>
</div>
```